# Mutating multiple columns in a data frame using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data frame `df`:

```
  v1 v2 v3 v4
1  1  5  7  4
2  2  6 10  3
```

And I want to obtain the following data frame `df2` multiplying columns v1*v3 and v2*v4:

```
  v1 v2 v3 v4 v1v3 v2v4
1  1  5  7  4    7   20
2  2  6 10  3   20   18
```

How can I do that using `dplyr`? Using `mutate_each`?

I need a solution that can be **generalized to a large number of variables** and not only 4 (v1 to v4).
This is the code to generate the example:

```
v1 <- c(1, 2)
v2 <- c(5,6)
v3 <- c(7, 10)
v4 <- c(4, 3)
df <- data.frame(v1, v2, v3, v4)
v1v3 <- c(v1 * v3)
v2v4 <- c(v2 * v4)
df2 <- cbind(df, v1v3, v2v4)
```

Comment: `df %>% mutate(v1v3=v1*v3) %>% mutate(v2v4=v2*v4)`

Comment: I edited my question. I need an answer that can be generalised to any number of variables without writing them all.

Comment: So you want to multiply values in alternate columns?

Comment: Yes, but the real case that I have is at this year one with 20 variables, not only 4 as in the example.

Comment: So for 20 variables you need output as `v1*v3*v5*v7...` or `v1*v3`, `v5*v7`, `v9*v11` etc. ?

Comment: No. I need output like v1*v11, v2*v12,...v10*v20.

Comment: Well, now: that is a different question :-D
You're essentially asking for someone to now code you a loop to generate your dplyr code. You're better off just multiplying your df1 by df2: Which metaphorically speaking, really is an entirely different ball of wax.

Comment: Please see my own answer below.

Comment: exactly, but that isn't written in tidyverse... ;-)  When you ask a question and then change it, it makes all the answers to the first question below it be 'wrong'. You are better off just selecting one of the responses that answered your question, and then asking your new question in a new thread. Your solution is fine, but it is not as good as some of the things you will get when you ask other folks how to solve that particular problem from the get go. Then you will get new cool ways to do things you don't already know - like dot products and dataframe to dataframe multiplications.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You are really close.

```
df2 <- 
    df %>% 
    mutate(v1v3 = v1 * v3,
           v2v4 = v2 * v4)
```

such a beautifully simple language, right?

For more great tricks please see [here.](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/data-wrangling-cheatsheet.pdf)

EDIT:
Thanks to @Facottons pointer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34377242/5088194, here is a *tidy* approach to resolving this issue. It keeps one from having to write a line to hard code in each new column desired. While it is a bit more verbose than the *Base R* approach, the logic is at least more immediately transparent/readable. It is also worth noting that there must be at least half as many rows as there are columns for this approach to work.

```
# prep the product column names (also acting as row numbers)
df <- 
    df %>%
    mutate(prod_grp = paste0("v", row_number(), "v", row_number() + 2)) 

# converting data to tidy format and pairing columns to be multiplied together.
tidy_df <- 
    df %>%
    gather(column, value, -prod_grp) %>% 
    mutate(column = as.numeric(sub("v", "", column)),
           pair = column - 2) %>% 
    mutate(pair = if_else(pair < 1, pair + 2, pair))

# summarize the products for each column
prod_df <- 
    tidy_df %>% 
    group_by(prod_grp, pair) %>% 
    summarize(val = prod(value)) %>% 
    spread(prod_grp, val) %>% 
    mutate(pair = paste0("v", pair, "v", pair + 2)) %>% 
    rename(prod_grp = pair)

# put the original frame and summary frames together
final_df <- 
    df %>% 
    left_join(prod_df) %>% 
    select(-prod_grp)
```

Comment: Now imagine you had 20 variables (`v1` to `v20`). Could you use `mutate`without writing 10 lines of code?

Comment: @Facottons - thanks for the poke. I have edited the answer above to include the tidy approach that you suggested.

Answer (score 4):

We can use `base R` instead of using any extra packages like `dplyr` or `data.table`

We can use `mapply` to vectorize the operation for multiple vectors at the same time

```
n <- ncol(df)/2
mapply(`*`, df[1:n], df[(n + 1):ncol(df)])

#     v1 v2
#[1,]  7 20
#[2,] 20 18
```

We can merge (`cbind`) this dataframe to your original one then.

---

If you are interested in `tidyverse` solution the equivalent in `purrr` would be variants of `map2`

```
purrr::map2_df(df[1:n], df[(n + 1):ncol(df)], `*`)

# A tibble: 2 x 2
#     v1    v2
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1     7    20
#2    20    18
```

Comment: Yes but I had a special interest in looking at a `dplyr` solution.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are looking for a `dplyr` solution ? I am not very much familiar with it. Maybe we can wait, somebody would answer it.

Answer (score 3):

I think I found a solution:

```
df %>%
  mutate(n = df[1:(ncol(df)/2)] * df[(1+ncol(df)/2):(ncol(df))]) %>% head()
```

The result is valid for any number of variables. It only remains a problem with the name of the new variables. This is the result:

```
  v1 v2 v3 v4 n.v1 n.v2
1  1  5  7  4    7   20
2  2  6 10  3   20   18
```

Comment: I am not sure how this works for you. It returns me an error `Error: Column \`n\` is of unsupported class data.frame`

Answer (score 2):

Just use mutate as is with a comma to separate new columns `mutate(df,"v1v3"=v1*v3,"v2v4"= v2*v4)`

Comment: Please see my comment above.

Answer (score 1):

I just found out!!!

In my case, I did:

`mutate (log2 (across (starts_with ("ratio"), .names = "log2_{.col}")))`

So I would transform to logarithm only the columns whose names started with "ratio". The new columns will have the same name as the originals, but their names will be preceded by the "log2_" prefix.

Comment: That's super helpful and exactly what I was looking for (a "modern" dplyr/tidyverse answer)!  It'd be great to drop in a pointer to your source for the `.names` argument.  I hadn't run across that previously.