# how to generate multiple columns with certain pattern in dplyr and purrr instead of using looping?

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to generate multiple new columns based on the current variable information in the data.frame (eg. data here), I can generate the variables with the loops using the scripts I listed below, is it possible to create them with the `mutate` command in **dplyr** with concise command? For example, using the mutate together with function, apply function or loop?

The requirement seems different from what have been achieved here
[Mutating multiple columns in a data frame using dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40511202/mutating-multiple-columns-in-a-data-frame-using-dplyr) and [Mutate multiple / consecutive columns (with dplyr or base R)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34377140/mutate-multiple-consecutive-columns-with-dplyr-or-base-r) as I want to create dozens of new columns with certain pattern based on one original variable.

```
data=data.frame(value=1:11,EV=seq(100,150,5))
q<-seq(-0.5,0.5,0.1)
data
EV=rep(NA,11)
for (i in 1:11){
value=assign(paste0('EV',i),data[,'EV']*(1+q[i]))
EV=cbind(EV,value)
}
EV=data.frame(EV[,2:12])
names(EV)<-paste0('EV',1:11)
EV
data.frame(data,EV)
```

Comment: @ANG seems not identical? how can I achieve the same effect as I listed if I use the `mutate` command here?